# Which one perform fast from JsonConvert.DeserializeObject or custom model bind in c#

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq

I want to know which one performs faster 
from JsonConvert.DeserializeObject or Custom model binding 
for Example:
My ViewModel class:

```
public class AssessmentViewModel : BaseViewModel
{
    public Guid AssessmentGUID { get; set; }

    public string AssessmentCategory { get; set; }

    public string AssessmentType { get; set; }

    public string AssessmentName { get; set; }

    public string AssessmentNameEnglish { get; set; }

    public string AssessmentInstruction { get; set; }

    public string AssessmentInstructionEnglish { get; set; }

    public int? SequenceNum { get; set; }

    public int? MaxScore { get; set; }

    public bool? IsNegativeMarking { get; set; }

    public decimal? NegativeRatio { get; set; }

    public List<StringMapDDLViewModel> AssessmentCategoryDDList { get; set; }

    public List<StringMapDDLViewModel> AssessmentTypeDDList { get; set; }

    public List<FOFormSectionViewModel> FOFormSectionList { get; set; }

    public List<StringMapDDLViewModel> FieldTypeList { get; set; }

    public List<StringMapDDLViewModel> ValidationTypeList { get; set; }
}
```

I am calling Stored Procedure and it returns 100 thousands of data.
So my question is which will perform faster from below code:

Method 1: Serialize result then Deserialize it.

```
 var assessmentList = db.AssessmentSP(Constant.ActionGetAll, null, status).ToList<AssessmentSP_Result>();
 objALVM.AssessmentList = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<AssessmentViewModel>>(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(assessmentList));
```

Method 2: One by one property binding

```
 var assessmentList = db.AssessmentSP(Constant.ActionGetAll, null, status).ToList<AssessmentSP_Result>().ToList();
                objALVM.AssessmentList = assessmentList.Select(x => new AssessmentViewModel()
                {
                     AssessmentGUID = x.AssessmentGUID,
                     AssessmentType = x.AssessmentType,
                     AssessmentName = x.AssessmentName,
                     AssessmentNameEnglish = x.AssessmentNameEnglish,
                     AssessmentInstruction = x.AssessmentInstruction,
                     AssessmentInstructionEnglish = x.AssessmentInstructionEnglish,
                     SequenceNum = x.SequenceNum,
                     MaxScore = x.MaxScore,
                     IsNegativeMarking = x.IsNegativeMarking,
                     NegativeRatio = x.NegativeRatio,
                }).ToList();
```

Comment: Why don't you set up an experiment and find out for yourself? See https://ericlippert.com/2012/12/17/performance-rant/

Comment: Second one will certainly be faster (at least after you remove 2 unnecessary `ToList()` calls). First might even not work at all and throw out of memory exception, because json with 100.000 items is quite a big string.

Comment: Thanks @Evk for your response

Comment: Total hogwash throwing out of memory exception for 100k+ item JSON string.